# Best Practice for find correct Child Class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have an abstract class Artifact and 2 classes Requirement and Feature which are children of Artifact.
Which would be the best way to implement a method where the input is an artifactID and the output would be the right child class of Artifact.

My code for that is this one:

```
Public MustInherit Class Artifact
    Public ReadOnly ID As String

    Public Sub New(ID As String)
        Me.ID = ID
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function [New](ID As String) As Artifact
        If ID.StartsWith("FE_") Then
            Return New Feature(ID)
        ElseIf ID.StartsWith("RQ_") Then
            Return New Requirement(ID)
        Else
            Throw New InvalidArtifactIDException("ID does not match to a known Artifacttype")
        End If
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Feature
    Inherits Artifact

    Public Requirements As List(Of Requirement)

    Sub New(ByVal FeatureID As String)
        MyBase.New(FeatureID)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Requirement
    Inherits Artifact

    Public Name As String

    Sub New(ByVal ReqID As String)
        MyBase.New(ReqID)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I don't know what to think about "Overwriting" the "New"-Keyword as methodname but it was the first Idea I had^^

Thanks for a response!

Comment: Maybe a good candidate for a Factory Design Pattern?

Comment: @Tim to apply to the Factory Design Pattern I would have to export the "new" method into a "Factory" class and rename it to GetArtifact? (like here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C.23)

Or do you have another approach in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the base class (Artifact) shouldn't even know that the derived classes (Feature and Requirement) exist. Artifact's constructor should handle initialization only of its own fields and properties, while the derived classes handle anything specific to those (see "Principle of Least Knowledge" and related principles [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658124.aspx)).

As @Tim mentions, this would be a perfect candidate for a [Factory pattern](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/napanchal/factory-pattern-in-VB-Net/). Sounds like you're on the right track with that -- you could implement it as a new class called ArtifactFactory with a GetArtifact() method (containing the logic of your [New] method in your code sample), and optionally add GetFeature() and GetRequirement() methods if you need those too.

Further reading for when you have time:

- [MSDN: Key Principles of Software Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658124.aspx)
- [DotNetCodr.com: SOLID Principles](http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/08/12/solid-design-principles-in-net-the-single-responsibility-principle/)
- [MSDN Magazine: Design Patterns You're Already Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx)